# Android: Data between Fragments and Activities

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass data between a fragment and an activity and I can't. I get no errors or exceptions. On my fragment I have the vallue and on activity that value is null. I'm using interfaces.

Code of HoroscopeChoice Fragment, which is the fragment with buttons. Each button has a value, which I want to pass to the activity every time I push them.

```
(...)
  static OnInfoChangedListener mCallback;

 public HoroscopeChoice() {}
    /******************************
     * Callback
     ********/
    public static void OnInfoChangedListener(OnInfoChangedListener callback) {
      mCallback = callback;
    }
    public interface OnInfoChangedListener {
        public void onInfoChanged(String horosocopo);
     }
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_horoscope_choice,
                container, false);

        Button aquarius;
        aquarius  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.aquarius1);

        final int id = view.getId();

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String horoscopo = onClick2(v.getId());
                Log.d("HoroscopeChoice", "push button->"+horoscopo);
                mCallback.onInfoChanged(horoscopo);
            }
        };

        aquarius.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

public String onClick2(int id)
{
    String horoscopo="";

    if (id == R.id.aquarius1) {
        horoscopo = "Aquarius";
    }
 }
(...)
```

Code of the Activity:

```
(...)
public void onInfoChanged(String horoscopo) {
        Log.d("SchedulerActivity","OnInfoChanged na Scheduler->"+horoscope);

        mHoroscopeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dailyHoroscope4);
        mHoroscopeDisplay.setText(horoscopo);
    }
```

When I do Log.d in the Fragment I get a value, on the Activity I have no value. Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: 1. How is `mCallback` being set? 2. Maybe the problem is inside of `onClick2()` method. What is in there?

Comment: @Karakuri I've forgotten to put it here, but I've added.  When I print the Log.d() I have on the code, I get a valid value in Fragment but in Activity no...

Comment: You have not added where `mCallback` is being _assigned_. You've only added where it is _declared_. I'm looking for something like `mCallback = {something}`

Comment: @Karakuri edited. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via interface callbacks, but there is an even easier way with a  great third party library called [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) that is perfect for this kind of thing. You can send **any** object from one place to the other.

All you need to do is post the Event and create a listener method wherever is needed. Follow their guide, it's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static listener object, especially to store something like an `Activity`. You should instead make the listener an instance variable. The standard pattern for using interface communication between Fragments and Activities is by using `onAttach()`.

```
private OnInfoChangedListener mCallback;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    if (!(activity instanceof OnInfoChangedListener)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement OnInfoChangedListener!");
    }
    mCallback = (OnInfoChangedListener) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null;
}
```

Comment: After made your changes, I still dont get the value on the activity. I think the problem is on the Activity but I don't know where.

Comment: @porthfind then you probably need to include more code in your post